# I'm getting a syntax error in my code

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a simple batch file for homework, it's just supposed to check if two variables are defined or not. I had it working fine, then I realized it needed to check two variables, not one. It still works but it gets a syntax error. anyone have any idea why?

```
:: 04/09/18
:: checkVars.bat
:: Checks if a variable name is defined


if %1 == "" (
  echo "Usage: %0 varname1"
  exit /b
) else (
  goto check
)


:check
if defined %1 (
    echo "%1 is defined"
) else (
    echo "%1 is not defined"    
)

shift /1
goto check
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.The error occurs when there are no command line arguments and first if is interpreted like  `if == ""` - which is a wrong syntax:

```
:: 04/09/18
:: checkVars.bat
:: Checks if a variable name is defined
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1" == "" (
  echo Usage: %0 varname1 [varname2 [..]]
  exit /b
) else (
  goto check
)


:check
set "arg=%~1"
if not "%~1" equ "" (
    if defined !arg! (
        echo "'%~1' is defined"
    ) else (
        echo "'%~1' is not defined"

    )
) else (
    goto :endcheck
)

shift /1
goto check
:endcheck
```

You'll have the same problem with the `if defined` too.To make it more robust you can use delayed expansion and you'll need a way to exit the checking otherwise you'll hit a never ending loop.Mind that using `goto` will hit the performance of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use a `For` loop:

```bat
Rem 04/09/18
Rem checkVars.bat
Rem Checks if variable names are defined
@Echo Off
If "%~1"=="" (Echo Usage: "%~0" "varname1" "varname2" etc. & Exit /B)
For %%A In (%*) Do If Defined %%~A (Echo "%%~A is defined"
) Else Echo "%%A is not defined"
Pause
```

You'll probably only need to surround `varname1`, `varname2` etc. with double quotes should they contain spaces, *(but it's always good practice).*

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you supply just one argument, `var1`.

The code will check "%1" which will be `var1`, but then it executes `shift` which replaces each %*n* with %*n+1* - and with just one argument, `%2` was empty, so now `%1` is empty, so your code will return to `:check` but attempt to execute `if defined (` (since `%1` is now empty) - and that's a syntax-error.

The easy way to fix your *existing* code is

```
:: 04/09/18
:: checkVars.bat
:: Checks if a variable name is defined


if "%1" == "" (
  echo "Usage: %0 varname1"
  exit /b
) else (
  goto check
)


:check
if defined %1 (
    echo "%1 is defined"
) else (
    echo "%1 is not defined"    
)

shift /1
if "%1" == "" (
  echo "Finished"
  exit /b
)
goto check
```

so that looping back to `check` will only occur if `%1` exists

Note : In *both* cases of this line, use

```
if "%1" == "" (
```

not

```
if %1 == "" (
```

as the `==` operator is very literal. The strings on *both* sides must be identical to achieve equivalence.